# executing pm2 from user gitlab-runner but running under root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, sudo, pm2

I need to launch my pm2 application using gitlab-runner user. This user have sudo privileges.

Need either to launch this pm2 process for root from user gitlab-runner. Or to make pm2 work properly under gitlab-runner user.

When I execute `/usr/local/bin/pm2 start npm -- start --user root` the process works only for gitlab-runner user. And then my site doesnt work. Command works only with root user. Sudo doesn't helps this way.